# Individiaul MySQL INSERT statements vs writing to local CSV first and then LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, performance, csv

I'm trying to extract information from 50 million HTML files into a MySQL database. My question is at what point during the process should I store the information into the MySQL database. For example, I'm considering these options:

1. Open each file and extract the information I need. Perform an INSERT after each file gets parsed.
2. Open each file and extract the information I need. Store the information into a CSV file as an intermediary. After all the files have been parsed into the CSV, perform a bulk upload using LOAD DATA INFILE

I know that LOAD DATA INFILE is much faster than individual INSERT statements if I already have the information in a CSV. However, if I don't have the information already in a CSV, I don't know if it's faster to create the CSV first.

At the crux of the question: Is writing to a local CSV faster or about the same as a single INSERT statement?

I'm using PHP in case it matters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a tossup.  The CSV has the extra overhead of writing the file, but is faster at doing the actual inserts.

Comment: This is a non-question.  The bulk of your time will be spend opening the files and parsing them, not on doing the `INSERTs`/`LOAD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key is not to do one insert per entry, but batch the entries in memory then perform a batch insert.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

ORMs like SQLAlchemy or Hibernate are smart enough (depending on configuration) to automatically batch your inserts.

Comment: I recommend 100 to 1000 rows per batch.